# how to check three conditions with IF Operator?

Tags: c#

i need to get three text(string) values to a if condition and check if all the three inputs are = to my conditions, then shows a message box "True".

simple way of saying i need to check three condition inside a if conditions

**Note:** i have already created set and get class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//
namespace KBS_Task3
{

    class PredecessorDAO
    {
           public void check(predecessor predecessor)
           {
           string predic = predecessor.getPredic();
           string arg1 = predecessor.getArg1();
           string arg2 = predecessor.getArg2();

           if(predic = "ISA" && (arg1="Car" && arg2="Vehicle"))
              {
              MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
              }
           }
     }
}
```

Above mentioned is the PredecessorDAO class

get and set called from Predecessor Class

Windows form has 3 combo box fields.

Comment: Your code works if you replace `=` with `==`, so what is the issue?

Comment: Check `=` or `==`?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation on C# operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx)?

Comment: As @doctorlove mentiones, a comparison is 2 "=" signs. 1 "=" sign is to set the value of a parameter

Comment: OMG i was big fool how come i missed that == point ? thanks all :), its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong operator to check for equality. You use the [assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx). But what you need is the [equality operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx). The former allows you to assign a value to a variable and the latter one allows you to compare 2 strings.

Using the equality operator the result would be:

```
public void check(predecessor predecessor)
{
      string predic = predecessor.getPredic();
      string arg1 = predecessor.getArg1();
      string arg2 = predecessor.getArg2();

      if(predic == "ISA" && arg1 == "Car" && arg2 == "Vehicle")
      {
          MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
      }
}
```

the parentheses in the middle are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks mate it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just want to check if 3 variable are equal to 3 values. You are correct to use the `&&` operator however when performing conditional operations you need to use the `==` operator instead of the `=` operator.

Use the `=` operator when you want to set the value of something.

Use the `==` operator when you want to check if one object is equal to another.

So you should be able to replace:

```
if(predic = "ISA" && (arg1="Car" && arg2=" {
    MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
}
```

With:

```
if(predic == "ISA" && arg1 == "Car" && arg2 == "Vehicle") {
    MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro it works